# Histogram in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, histogram

I have the following problem:

> Define a function `histogram :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]` such that
>   `histogram n xs` returns a list that counts the frequency of
>   values drawn from `xs` in the ranges `0..n-1, n..2n-1, 2n..3n-1, ...` and
>   so on, until all values in `xs` have been counted. For example,
>   `histogram 5 [1, 2, 10, 4, 7, 12]` **=>** `[3, 1, 2]`.

I have tried various approaches to this problem including first defining a function `range` which produces list of tuples like: `range 3` **=>** `[(0,2),(3,5),...]` to infinity, but I cannot seem to find appropriate solution to the whole problem. Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your `range` function is a good start.  Can you `filter` a list for all the items in a given range?

Comment: Please add your code which is tried.

Comment: @luqui Unfortunately no, not yet. I am only familiar with the topic Types and Classes, Defining functions, List comprehensions and Recursive functions

Comment: `filter`can also be done using a list comprehension.  For example `[ x | x <- xs, x < 5 ]` selects all the elements of the list `xs` that are less than 5.

Comment: @luqui Thank you a lot. Just a last question. How can takeWhile be done then?

Comment: @Belle, I don't think `takeWhile` can be done using a list comprehension, you have to write that as a recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

We can start by generating ranges required, and then map `count` function onto ranges to get list of partial functions, which finally can be applied on the given list.

```
ranges lim n = takeWhile (\(x,y) -> x < lim) [(k*n, (k+1)*n - 1) | k <- [0..]]

count (l,r) = length.filter (\x -> l <= x && x <= r)

histogram n xs = (map count range ) <*> [xs] where range =(ranges (maximum xs) n)

-- OR

histogram n xs = count <$> range <*> pure xs where range =(ranges (maximum xs) n)

--OR, if you are unfamiliar with applicatives

histogram n xs = go funcs
                   where range =(ranges (maximum xs) n)
                         funcs = (map count range)
                         go [] = []
                         go (f:fs) = (f xs): (go fs)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without the filter function as according to the problem we still have not covered higher-order functions, only Types and Classes, Defining functions, List comprehensions and Recursive functions

Comment: @Belle: yes, that is possible.

Comment: @Belle: if you know how to create recursive functions you can easily implement `filter` on your own

Comment: @Yogendra But what does length.filter mean, what is this dot between the two functions?

Comment: `.` is used for composing functions, In this case you can think of it as first applying `filter` on input and then applying `length` on the result of filter. If you have two functions `f :: a -> b` and `g :: b -> c` , on composing them you get `f.g :: a ->c`. if you are uncomfortable with this you can write `count ` as `count (l,r) xs = length (filter (\x -> l <= x && x <= r) xs)`

Comment: @Yogendra thank you. Last question. How can takeWhile be written in another way?

Comment: @Belle similar to filter you can implement takeWhile on your own via recursive function, since it takes values from list until predicate is true, it can be something like `takeWhile' f (x:xs) = if (f x) then x:(takeWhile' f xs) else []`

Comment: equivalent code: `histogram n xs = [count range xs | range <- ranges (maximum xs) n]`.